# Enter tds in multiple lines which are all inside a single tr

Tags: html, css

Hi every one,
I need to enter td values in multiple lines which are all inside a single tr.
I tried like this but could not achieve it.

```
<table class="table">
<tr style="margin-bottom:10px;border:5px solid lightgrey;width:700px">
<td style="width:500px">.... </td>
<td style="width:300px">.... </td>
<td style="width:500px">.... </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I thought that because of the mentioned width for tds it will wrap to the next line but it was not. Even after increasing the td width beyond 700px i could not get the expected output.

How to fix this?

Comment: what do u mean by "multiple lines" can u show some sample output.

Comment: @CRDave:multiple line in the sense,line by line,say first td in line 1,second td in line 2 and so on.

Comment: @Sree:NO i need to do it using tables.

Comment: can you show some picture of what are you trying to do?

Comment: <TD> is to make column and you want to create row from that. That is not possible. U have tow way to do in <TABLE> use <TR><TD>line1</TD></TR> for every line of separate each line with <BR> tag like : <TR><TD>line1<br>line2..</TD></TR>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your `TD` elements to `display: block;` which will force them onto new lines:

```
​.table td { display: block; }​
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fPHj/)

Comment: how to make if i nee 3 td in each row

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this....

> td1
>   td2
>   td3

if, why don't you use

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>TD1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TD2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

OR if you want to group tds in one tr

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>TD1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>TD2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>TD3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    <tr>
<table>
```

BTW, if this is not a must to use td for the **tds information**, you may try this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            TD1 information<br/>
            TD2 information<br/>
            TD3 information<br/>
        </td>
    <tr>
<table>
```

Comment: @ Michael Law:ya i need exactly as u mentioned but i need to achieve it inside a single tr.

Answer (score 0):

Use for the first line :

```
table tr td:nth-child(1)
{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Use for the second line :

```
table tr td:nth-child(2)
{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

ect.

To support IE 7 & 8 you need to use :

```
td:first-child + td
```

for the first second line

```
td:first-child + td + td
```

for the 3rd.

ect.

to support IE6 you need to use Javascript.

```
$(function() {
    $('td:first-child').addClass("Class1");
    $(".table-class tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find('td:eq(1)').addClass("Class2");
        $(this).find('td:eq(2)').addClass("Class3");
    });
});
```

This will add a class that you can call